# JAVA Problems sending email in HTML format with embedded image

Tags: java, email, liferay

Hello guys i lost two hours to solve this problem.

I have a Java class that send mail and the body inside is in HTML format

here that method

```
private void sendMail() {


      String body                      = "<html><body><p>Mr.<b>Jack Frusciante</b><br/>Work : <b>Programmer</b><br/><img alt=\"Firm\" src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKAAAACgCAMAAAC8EZcfAAAA7VBMVEX///90yW8IZGXp9uYAWlsAYWJRg4SNqqoAXl9wyGuzzs72/PVyo6QAU1QddHUAWVrs8vJtx2ef2Zz5/fkSbW7t+Oub2JjZ5+doxWKGz4J7zHYAYWXH2dnh7OyN0olBgoJbrXrc8duCzn0ATU+lxMTQ7M7A5b+T1I+n3KSy4K+UubrW7tUudHWbuLiBrq7J6MZPiJBpmpqv2rRXlZZHjI3B0NC14LNjnZx+pqe309I6eHlXrnE+h4iHyo+qy8ZxtJCUwLJmsYRGm2sbc2ZrwG5Spmw3jGh/rpw3eH+by6gAa2IxhmgCZXEAWGRgtW0uQDJmAAAF9ElEQVR4nO2Ya3uiZhCGESHhIAICi6JoZDHGeCrVZNVs0+22Tdttu///53RmOKhRs1F77e6HuT9ErpHAw7zzzDsoCAzDMAzDMAzDMAzDMAzDMAzDMAzDMAzDMAzDMAxzDo6Ffz0dD51vrGUfrSSp+N5Nv9YTdI9kfl+0Voqi/Bmpqhr1ysB3p3Asi6LYfCiVSuqNBwK9by0IsFq+77dSun+QwI97BTp6xtGlCTfwrZMFhu9Wnc7IJZ4e3KbY/CdSS6Vg6m0vsT6oZdzcd4/TN+p0Vq2TBQr6xDUMU4Hcye7DQ/PfT39NG7Z9L+jbJVjGysyIro+5QWzKsuGfLhAJtUoHF/fvEty+Xva8XQcPIa0F9fsjLp4o8Ozn6QOsCqSw+etvePvhPgNf2/BNEAQlElo/4tIXsijPz9XnzOAxRfF3tMdgn3+dGgiLrrvd4RsS+Hp/+yNZVG7PFZiQPrSvXdvbX/QGfNcu50f18vorb49YPy6KTnNF0TzDI8QC9TWfIElqv4sLvNNKvDq2Hgr31XUG9fuoDvRzX1feGm/n1kI2JaMapqFLWGEXu8zqrWG4GLGqcFZyRLdyFtT+sADV6Hl7ycASVMkaTqOoQWca2GQa1e6lp0G9KYuOhMshvUvPgcWRZyiwAgdVDGmQDnf5en3CLeoTP33GBb7er0/AEgxIRS+A8xqpanSMiq5RI1rzcIWXMk0JP1Lnhh3QfClsCsTI7Ah9MelrPmEqGp63b4EFAVWRCHKLTY2wi/KC2oB8TZEWGEKUJuESPw36x1YV5NxtCvRNeAbtleIcy7qVSaAofsY7H9iCnXqq3pviNqM2KMeBCiULD+OR9zEyxuugIWaFwDsTZJFHYinNapJn8mVlod+608aLuStmND9hIoLp3ilmSLUGdsBPNV3rMoi20R16lNcnmE3uYL0l6AwhD83DXKCRth3piwlcJrNOVZQkhdKnuOSSJ2zT7b1t+n5jH1GDaRGr46bTxSjGQvIIFkjRnK05hoQNgejq+RdnB0sxJSXHnPlLAyV+xOW7QYHlZ+f31wLVdnkj1gAizPxQyJIT4wGYRZnQjWCF5LRNt0wUGKLiV1SgnlRyJthTfbCW6F7hOpKRtxVScy6RklKgb8ZyqCrv8BpYb+vmjKrcVI9PAmNFVJJThq8Qy+aHH7HVeDutBluL2te77Y1NhNpNPt/YbzA0xhLEx6XBl1RMILRKd5WQBEICxfgEfbAYY0muWr0IFXjPBF6XyAbODRp9uo6V+m8ysMtYSZ4ddMZ7Egh65IvsKga0oJYEz3Dq25gMAoUbGLeez4ICtrr6MPVF2lDSWMODOdshUGA168lYL6lZBMiakqwFytB/Xt0Dd3ivgMB7GwQ62wI98gNEplSERSzVSu8CeBCCAlq+dXP2MWu5IPy6aD+n8E4CgT0S6G1P0w0qQdg7sE2n+3C5rWarXQuigErwFpZvRCUo5c35FltLNjUI1MxE5bQKTK8GAofkgm2BQzUbZbyocAkJxMobwoZSp40OZkoSGGICU6dWcEzKL1OlHbpz+vtTbILAbrQrEEeZdF5pq/kRClSjwXSABo/obMrQXGthx8qcig37/ZbAMxIoWAYILLdRoL71QofmjWjkwyO1RtEBTTI2DQzYpQXHoBWUTLkwBg4PacNGcIOWL0LhZCwRBHr9XYENENKnCeLahqbXpiimkLCjdBjU0LGTEb4iSZ1UhiYqslFM0/RaMX5JQXz5IgvXjTXtp4dHTXt8hD85j1fAzxT4gIe/pN99uHqwgWiQdW7oyaIpLOem6S6ygT+ezWbrbQOWWF69VIHW3JBeRHF9y9Kt1zOc9rzilwasNxijrDC08pCDJxW3hweQXnx7shYXX2B2usNoml7X2+7NcZI4oweezxIHhLsDX44nCXpcPuZN5P+GpukDFg1HEhpEPpzgr8ClcrgJLyF9siwtvq6ibXAQlQ8NepjdUedbri+YQBvH40M/ILTGcXzujwsMwzAMwzAMwzAMwzAMwzAMwzAMwzAMwzAMwzAM8z3xHzxMgUvIvKzHAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\"/><br/><p>Lorem ipsum</p></p></body></html>";

        SendMail sendMail = new SendMail("jack@gmail.com","othermail@gmail.com","subject","");
        sendMail.setCC("othermailcc@gmail.com");
        sendMail.setBody(body);
        sendMail.send();

    }
```

and here the SendMail class

```
package com.jack.util;


import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility;
import javax.mail.internet.PreencodedMimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;


import com.liferay.mail.service.MailServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.mail.MailMessage;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.mail.SMTPAccount;
import com.liferay.util.mail.MailEngine;
import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPMessage;

public class SendMail {

    private String from;
    private String subject;
    private String body;        
    private String to;
    private String cc;
    private String cid;
    private String smtpHost;
    private String smtpPort;
    private Boolean authenticationRequired;
    private String authenticationUsername;
    private String authenticationPassword;




    public SendMail(String from,String to,String subject,String body) {
        super();
        this.to = to;
        this.from = from;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.body = body;

    }






    public String getSmtpHost() {
        return smtpHost;
    }





    public void setSmtpHost(String smtpHost) {
        this.smtpHost = smtpHost;
    }





    public String getSmtpPort() {
        return smtpPort;
    }





    public void setSmtpPort(String smtpPort) {
        this.smtpPort = smtpPort;
    }





    public Boolean getAuthenticationRequired() {
        return authenticationRequired;
    }





    public void setAuthenticationRequired(Boolean authenticationRequired) {
        this.authenticationRequired = authenticationRequired;
    }





    public String getAuthenticationUsername() {
        return authenticationUsername;
    }





    public void setAuthenticationUsername(String authenticationUsername) {
        this.authenticationUsername = authenticationUsername;
    }





    public String getAuthenticationPassword() {
        return authenticationPassword;
    }





    public void setAuthenticationPassword(String authenticationPassword) {
        this.authenticationPassword = authenticationPassword;
    }





    public void setCC(String cc) {
        this.cc=cc;
    }








    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }


    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }


    public void send() {

        new Thread( new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public synchronized void run() {

                performSend();
            }

        }).start();

    }

    private void performSend() {

        try {
            Session session = getSession();

             SMTPMessage transport = new SMTPMessage(session);
            InternetAddress iaFrom = new InternetAddress(from, from);
            InternetAddress iaTo   = new InternetAddress(to,to);
            InternetAddress iaCC   = (cc!=null) ?  new InternetAddress(cc,cc) : null;
            MimeMultipart mailMessage = new MimeMultipart("related");
            BodyPart bp = new MimeBodyPart();
            bp.setContent(body,"text/html");
            mailMessage.addBodyPart(bp);
            transport.setContent(mailMessage);
            transport.setFrom(iaFrom);
            if(iaCC!=null) {
                transport.setRecipient(RecipientType.CC,  iaCC);
            }

            transport.setSubject(subject);
            InternetAddress[] recipients = { iaTo };
            Transport.send(transport, recipients);
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }


     private Session getSession() {
            Properties mailProps = new Properties();
            mailProps.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            mailProps.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            mailProps.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            mailProps.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            mailProps.put("mail.smtp.auth",  "true" );
            mailProps.put("mail.smtp.port","465");
                return  Session.getInstance(mailProps,
                        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                return new PasswordAuthentication("jack","jackpassword");
                            }
                        }); 

     }




}
```

the mail arrives but image at the of html is never showed . I noted , inspected the source of message, that img tag is changed like this

```
<img alt=3D"Firm" src=3D"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA=
NSUhEUgAAAKAAAACgCAMAAAC8EZcfAAAA7VBMVEX///90yW8IZGXp9uYAWlsAYWJRg4SNqqoAXl=
9wyGuzzs72/PVyo6QAU1QddHUAWVrs8vJtx2ef2Zz5/fkSbW7t+Oub2JjZ5+doxWKGz4J7zHYAY=
WXH2dnh7OyN0olBgoJbrXrc8duCzn0ATU+lxMTQ7M7A5b+T1I+n3KSy4K+UubrW7tUudHWbuLiB=
rq7J6MZPiJBpmpqv2rRXlZZHjI3B0NC14LNjnZx+pqe309I6eHlXrnE+h4iHyo+qy8ZxtJCUwLJ=
msYRGm2sbc2ZrwG5Spmw3jGh/rpw3eH+by6gAa2IxhmgCZXEAWGRgtW0uQDJmAAAF9ElEQVR4nO=
2Ya3uiZhCGESHhIAICi6JoZDHGeCrVZNVs0+22Tdttu///53RmOKhRs1F77e6HuT9ErpHAw7zzz=
DsoCAzDMAzDMAzDMAzDMAzDMAzDMAzDMAzDMAzDMAxzDo6Ffz0dD51vrGUfrSSp+N5Nv9YTdI9k=
fl+0Voqi/Bmpqhr1ysB3p3Asi6LYfCiVSuqNBwK9by0IsFq+77dSun+QwI97BTp6xtGlCTfwrZM=
Fhu9Wnc7IJZ4e3KbY/CdSS6Vg6m0vsT6oZdzcd4/TN+p0Vq2TBQr6xDUMU4Hcye7DQ/PfT39NG7=
Z9L+jbJVjGysyIro+5QWzKsuGfLhAJtUoHF/fvEty+Xva8XQcPIa0F9fsjLp4o8Ozn6QOsCqSw+=
etvePvhPgNf2/BNEAQlElo/4tIXsijPz9XnzOAxRfF3tMdgn3+dGgiLrrvd4RsS+Hp/+yNZVG7P=
FZiQPrSvXdvbX/QGfNcu50f18vorb49YPy6KTnNF0TzDI8QC9TWfIElqv4sLvNNKvDq2Hgr31XU=
G9fuoDvRzX1feGm/n1kI2JaMapqFLWGEXu8zqrWG4GLGqcFZyRLdyFtT+sADV6Hl7ycASVMkaTq=
OoQWca2GQa1e6lp0G9KYuOhMshvUvPgcWRZyiwAgdVDGmQDnf5en3CLeoTP33GBb7er0/AEgxIR=
S+A8xqpanSMiq5RI1rzcIWXMk0JP1Lnhh3QfClsCsTI7Ah9MelrPmEqGp63b4EFAVWRCHKLTY2w=
i/KC2oB8TZEWGEKUJuESPw36x1YV5NxtCvRNeAbtleIcy7qVSaAofsY7H9iCnXqq3pviNqM2KMe=
BCiULD+OR9zEyxuugIWaFwDsTZJFHYinNapJn8mVlod+608aLuStmND9hIoLp3ilmSLUGdsBPNV=
3rMoi20R16lNcnmE3uYL0l6AwhD83DXKCRth3piwlcJrNOVZQkhdKnuOSSJ2zT7b1t+n5jH1GDa=
RGr46bTxSjGQvIIFkjRnK05hoQNgejq+RdnB0sxJSXHnPlLAyV+xOW7QYHlZ+f31wLVdnkj1gAi=
zPxQyJIT4wGYRZnQjWCF5LRNt0wUGKLiV1SgnlRyJthTfbCW6F7hOpKRtxVScy6RklKgb8ZyqCr=
v8BpYb+vmjKrcVI9PAmNFVJJThq8Qy+aHH7HVeDutBluL2te77Y1NhNpNPt/YbzA0xhLEx6XBl1=
RMILRKd5WQBEICxfgEfbAYY0muWr0IFXjPBF6XyAbODRp9uo6V+m8ysMtYSZ4ddMZ7Egh65IvsK=
ga0oJYEz3Dq25gMAoUbGLeez4ICtrr6MPVF2lDSWMODOdshUGA168lYL6lZBMiakqwFytB/Xt0D=
d3ivgMB7GwQ62wI98gNEplSERSzVSu8CeBCCAlq+dXP2MWu5IPy6aD+n8E4CgT0S6G1P0w0qQdg=
7sE2n+3C5rWarXQuigErwFpZvRCUo5c35FltLNjUI1MxE5bQKTK8GAofkgm2BQzUbZbyocAkJxM=
obwoZSp40OZkoSGGICU6dWcEzKL1OlHbpz+vtTbILAbrQrEEeZdF5pq/kRClSjwXSABo/obMrQX=
Gthx8qcig37/ZbAMxIoWAYILLdRoL71QofmjWjkwyO1RtEBTTI2DQzYpQXHoBWUTLkwBg4PacNG=
cIOWL0LhZCwRBHr9XYENENKnCeLahqbXpiimkLCjdBjU0LGTEb4iSZ1UhiYqslFM0/RaMX5JQXz=
5IgvXjTXtp4dHTXt8hD85j1fAzxT4gIe/pN99uHqwgWiQdW7oyaIpLOem6S6ygT+ezWbrbQOWWF=
69VIHW3JBeRHF9y9Kt1zOc9rzilwasNxijrDC08pCDJxW3hweQXnx7shYXX2B2usNoml7X2+7Nc=
ZI4oweezxIHhLsDX44nCXpcPuZN5P+GpukDFg1HEhpEPpzgr8ClcrgJLyF9siwtvq6ibXAQlQ8N=
epjdUedbri+YQBvH40M/ILTGcXzujwsMwzAMwzAMwzAMwzAMwzAMwzAMwzAMwzAMwzAM8z3xHzx=
MgUvIvKzHAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"/>
```

and the body part starts with

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Anybody have an idea to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This does not answer the question but apache supports an excellent mailing api within apache commons: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/.

Comment: use  table tag to align the content in mail body, and upload images in documents and media  and access images by url

Answer (score 0):

I think there was some problem similar to "twice encoding"... or something like.

You should try to understand how body message is transformed, inside the steps of sending process.

A smart alternative, if the image is in your document library and it is pubblic accessible, is to provide the URL instead the full-image content inside your email body... this may help you to avoid several potential issues related to SMTP protocol and mail server loading.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I suggest you to save your image in an image server and include its reference in the message body. Of course this solution will work as long as the image is available in the specific server that you use.

As and example, I uploaded your image to *Imgur* server and here is a simpler version to send mail from java:

```
package stack;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMail{

    public static void main(String emailAddress){


        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String from = "yourMail@gmail.com";
        String subject = "Testing java mail";       
        String contentBody = "<html>\n" + "<body>\n"
                + "<p>Mr.<b>Jack Frusciante</b>\n"
                + "<br/>Work : <b>Programmer</b><br/>\n"
                + "<img src =\"http://imgur.com/81h91BL.png\"/>\n" + "<br/>\n"
                + "<p>Lorem ipsum</p></p>\n" + "</body>\n" + "</html>";                 



        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", "");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");


        try{
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            InternetAddress to_address = new InternetAddress(emailAddress.toLowerCase());


            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);     
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, to_address);
            message.setSubject(subject);                    
            message.setContent(contentBody, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");



            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "yourMail@gmail.com", "yourPassword");
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();

            System.out.println("This notification was sent to : " + emailAddress +"");
            }

            catch (MessagingException mex) {
            System.out.println("send failed, exception: " + mex);
            }
    }

}
```